# Remove unicode from string

Tags: python, string, unicode

I'm trying to remove special character from Arabic String using it's Unicode which I got from this link:
https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0640/index.htm

This is my code:

```
TATWEEL = u"\u0640"
text = 'الســلام عليكــم'

text.replace(TATWEEL, '')
print(text)
```

But I tried it and doesn't work (it prints the same string without removing the character)

This is the special character 'ــ'

[image]

I'm using Python3

Comment: when you say it *doesn't work* what do you mean? Did you receive an error or the pc you were using exploded?

Comment: No it prints the same text without removing the character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing or substituting in a python string does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780139/replacing-or-substituting-in-a-python-string-does-not-work)

Answer (score 8):

The `replace` method of strings does not change the string it is called on; it returns a new string with the specified character replaced.

This code does what you want:

```
TATWEEL = u"\u0640"
text = 'الســلام عليكــم'

text2 = text.replace(TATWEEL, '')
print(text2)
```

To get the exact result you expected, use this:

```
text = text.replace(TATWEEL, '')
print(text)
```

Comment: @user8393084 If it works for you, please accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

If text may contain multiple unicode elements then you should go for regex as below:

```
import re
TATWEEL = u"\u0640"
text = 'الســلام عليكــم'

unicode_removed_text = re.sub(TATWEEL, '', text)
```

Comment: How is this better than `replace`?

Comment: refer this [ink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668947/use-pythons-string-replace-vs-re-sub); it's very good explanation on where to use replace() and where re.sub()

Comment: First answer says *if you can use `replace`, use it*

Comment: I still don't understand the rationale from your post "*If text may contain multiple unicode elements then you should go for regex*"